# Parallel Foreach with large list throws exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a large list (1000 or more) and I'm using `Parallel.Foreach` to loop it, but I get this exception:

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()

Please let me know why I get this exception and give me a solution to resolve it, and how I can improve performance of parallel `foreach`?

```
var results = new List<BO>();
var localLockObject = new object();

Parallel.ForEach(
  emails,
  () => new List<BO>(), (email, state, localList) =>
  {
      var item = new BO();
      localList.Add(item.Validate(email));
      return localList;
  },
  finalResult => { lock (localLockObject) results.AddRange(finalResult); }
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that is where the exception is being thrown? Can you click "[Copy Exception Details to clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx)" and post the full text as a edit to your question? That will also let us see any inner exceptions or messages associated with it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Parallel.ForEach` declaration seems to fine,  I'm not sure this is the place generating the exception.

However, a better solution for this use case would be to use 
[PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) which won't require synchronization:

```
var result = emails.AsParallel()
                   .Select(email => 
                    { 
                       var item = new BO();
                       return item.Validate(email);
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: pls read comment below, It's too long so I can insert to here